# Docker: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

[root@mymachine redisc]# ls
app.py  Dockerfile  redis.conf  redis-server  requirements.txt

[root@mymachine redisc]# cat Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim
#FROM alpine:3.7

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/x/build/"]

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 6379

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME Redis

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["/app/redis-server", "/app/redis_rtp.conf"]
```

I've built the image as myredis

```
[root@mymachine redisc]# docker run -p 6379:6379

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 104
>>> 'logfile /x/build/redis/logs/redis_6379_container.log'
Can't open the log file: No such file or directory
```

the above gave me an error so I've tried supplying the path

```
[root@mymachine redisc]# docker run -p 6379:6379 -v /x/build/redis/log myredis
```

It gave me the same error but the dir exists.

```
[root@mymachine9 redisc]# ls /x/build/redis/logs/

redis2_6379.log  redis_6379.log
```

Why isn't the dir not accessible from the container? how can I fix it?

thank you

Comment: Maybe because of permissions? Can you `docker run -it -[...] myredis /bin/sh` and check within the container?

Comment: you may also specify where the directory has to be mounted with `-v /x/build/redis/logs:/x/build/redis/logs`

Comment: `[root@mymachine9 redisc]# ls /x/build/redis/logs/` is in the container or host OS?

Comment: @SangminKim host OS

Comment: @fernandezcuesta -v /x/build/redis/logs:/x/build/redis/logs works. would i just write the same thing in VOLUME in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @ealeon exactly

Answer (score 0):

`VOLUME ["/x/build/"]` means that you want to mount `/x/build/` dir of a container into the host OS.

In contrast, I think you expect that the container mounts `/x/build/` of host OS into the container.

That is why I asked `[root@mymachine9 redisc]# ls /x/build/redis/logs/` is in the container or host OS and that is why docker returns the error `No such file or directory`.

Because docker will just have just empty `/x/build/` dir.
(if the base image doesn't have the `/x/build/`, docker will create the dir)

For example,

```
# Add into you Dockferfile
RUN mkdir -p /testDir && touch /testDir/test && echo "test1234" >> /testDir/test
VOLUME ["/testDir"]

---------

# Run a container
$ docker run --name test image_name

# Check mount position
$ docker inspect test -f {{.Mounts}}   
[{volume 09e3cedef5ceeef0cbd944785e0ea629d4c65a20b10d1384bbd50a1c67879845 /var/lib/docker/volumes/09e3cedef5ceeef0cbd944785e0ea629d4c65a20b10d1384bbd50a1c67879845/_data /testDir local  true }]

# Move to mount position
$ cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/09e3cedef5ceeef0cbd944785e0ea629d4c65a20b10d1384bbd50a1c67879845/_data 
 
# Check if the content is from testDir of base image.
$ ls 
test
$ cat test 
test1234
```

As `@fernandezcuesta` comment, you can use [bind](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount) option for your purpose.

```
-v /x/build/redis/logs:/x/build/redis/logs
or 
--mount type=bind,source=/x/build/redis/logs,target=/x/build/redis/logs
```

-----**Edit**-----

For now, there is no way to do `bind` option in `Dockerfile`, that is while building an image. Refer this [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1191), you can find why docker doesn't support that.

In short

> - bind mounts are linked to the host, as Dockerfiles can be shared, it would break compatibility (a Dockerfile with your bind mounts won't work on my machine)
> - bind mounts are more related to the run than to the build.

Comment: right, i want host OS dir to inside of a container. how can i denote -v within Dockerfile, then?